# Trying to run one command in "Execute Shell" and a python script in Jenkins (formerly hudson) under "build"

Tags: jenkins

These run on the command line in linux (ubuntu) but when trying to run them via hudson, only the first one (first one) shows up in the console Output

**From comment:**

1. nosetests -s --with-coverage --cover-package prus find . -name "*test.py"
2. pylint --rcfile scripts/pylintrc -f parseable prus > pylint.txt echo "pylint complete"
3. sloccount --wide --details prus > sloccount.sc

Comment: Can you post the commands that you run?

Comment: 1. nosetests -s --with-coverage --cover-package prus `find . -name "*test.py"`
2. pylint --rcfile  scripts/pylintrc -f parseable prus  > pylint.txt echo "pylint complete"
3. sloccount --wide --details prus > sloccount.sc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your piping the output from 2 into pylint.txt, and 3 is being piped into sloccount.sc. You need to pipe to both stdout and to the file in order to get your files populates, as well as have the output go to Hudson. Take a look at tee.exe, it will do that for you.